# Can a sum of products be split as a product of two sums?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have

$$\sum_k^n P_k x_k$$

Am I allowed to split it up into two sums so I have it like

$$\sum_k^n P_k  \sum_k^nx_k$$

Comment: No. But since $P_{n}$ doesn't depend on the sum (of $k$), you can take it out, and it becomes $P_{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}$.

Comment: In $\sum_k^nP_nx_k$, $P_n$ doesn't depend on $k$ so can be factored out.

Comment: Assuming that $P_n$ is a constant with respect to $k$, the above comments are true.

Comment: $2 = 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1 \neq (1+1)\cdot(1+1) = 4$.

Comment: Where is your research? Did you try tackling the problem? Downvote.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

$\qquad\qquad$ [image]

$$x_1\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x_2\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x_3\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x_4$$

Imagine that the vertical segments are your $P$'s. Then the product of sums is the area of the entire rectangle, whereas the sum of products is only the red area.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming P depends on k and not n then the summation
$$
\sum_k P_k x_k
$$ 
Creates terms like
$$
P_1 x_1 + P_2 x_2 + \ldots + P_n x_n
$$
But, if you took $P_k$ out then you would have two independent sums:
$$
\sum_k P_k \sum_k x_k
$$
Producing two separate sums multiplying each other like
$$
(P_1 + P_2 + \ldots + P_n) (x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n)
$$
And this obviously produces terms like $P_1 x_1, P_1 x_2,\ldots$ or as produced by the double sum written like:
$$
\sum_i \sum_j P_i x_j
$$
So the original summation is definitely not the same as this double sum.

Answer (score 0):

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SummationNotation.aspx

^^^That offers a nice summary of summation notation and its properties.

To answer your question specifically, you should not split this into two different summations. Rather, notice that P does not depend on k. You can treat P as a constant and simply move it outside the summation so that it multiples the result of your summation of $x_k$, which does depend on your variable k.

Comment: actually I made a typo P depends on k and n.  I ask because I know that the the sum with the $P_nk is always equal to 1 for all n and k.  But thanks for the response, it does make sense with what I wrote!

Comment: That link answers my question though, I appreciate it thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to analyze the quantum, you can just use the Cauchy's inequality in n-dimensional Euclidean space, i.e.

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i\right)^2 \leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2\right)
$$