# In general, is the sum of a product less than or equal to the product of its sums?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was looking at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958758/can-a-sum-of-products-be-split-as-a-product-of-two-sums/958771) trying to understand more about the relation of sums, and it seems to suggest that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_ky_k\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_k
$$

Is this true in general, and in general if $n=\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the $x_k$ and $y_k$ all non-negative?  If so, the answer is obviously yes by expanding the right hand product, as shown in the red and blue chart in an answer to the linked question; the right hand side has every term on the left hand side plus many more non-negative terms

If some of the terms can be negative, consider $x_1=y_1=+1$ and $x_2=y_2=-1$, making the left hand side $2$ and the right hand side $0$